# How to set Dropdown List default value based on user selection

Tags: php

I have a dropdown list. However i want to set a default based on user selection. Therefore the default value is not consistent. What can i do to achieve this? I have set `$country = $_POST['country'];` as user selection.

```
<td>Country:</td>
<td colspan="2"><select name="country">
    <option value="93">93-Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="355">355-Albania</option>
    <option value="213">213-Algeria</option>
    <option value="1-684">1-684-American Samoa</option>
    <option value="376">376-Andorra</option>
    <option value="244">244-Angola</option>
    <option value="1-264">1-264-Anguilla</option>
    <option value="672">672-Antarctica</option>
    <option value="1-268">1-268-Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="54">54-Argentina</option>
    <option value="374">374-Armenia</option>
    <option value="297">297-Aruba</option>
    <option value="61">61-Australia</option>
</select>
```

To add on. There are 200 over options (I never list all down) so i hope to get a convenience way to achieve this

Comment: so you keep the items in a database and simply add a while loop

Comment: In this case, it will be a good practice to keep country data in database table and use while loop to read it. This will be easy to manage as well as to manipulate.

Comment: If not from database, have you used array for this?

Comment: @Suyog well nope too. I only need to use these for dropdownlist that is why i never key into database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using session for it.

The **php** code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['selectedCountry'] = $_POST['country'];
```

Then you can use **JQuery** to make dropdown selected:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
             $(function() {
                $("#country").val("<?php echo $_SESSION['selectedCountry'];?>");
             });
    })
```

Comment: i just add the session and the jquery in. I dont want to make others confused, hope you can understand.

Comment: okay, have you tried printing $_SESSION array? (just to make confirm that session has set).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90766/discussion-between-suyog-and-yan-shuang-low).

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'selected' for relevant option

```
<option value="93" <?php if($country==93) echo "selected" ?> >93-Afghanistan</option>
<option value="355" <?php if($country==355) echo "selected" ?> >355-Albania</option>
```

like this add if conditon for each option.

Comment: I had think of doing this but my drop down list have 200 over options so this will be very inconvenience

Comment: Is your values and names of them coming from a db @YanShuangLow, then it can do easily with a foreach loop

Comment: So you can use an array with values and names, along with foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Please try out this ..

```
HTML :-

        <td>Country:</td>
        <td colspan="2"><select id="country" name="country">
            <option value="93">93-Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="355">355-Albania</option>
            <option value="213">213-Algeria</option>
            <option value="1-684">1-684-American Samoa</option>
            <option value="376">376-Andorra</option>
            <option value="244">244-Angola</option>
            <option value="1-264">1-264-Anguilla</option>
            <option value="672">672-Antarctica</option>
            <option value="1-268">1-268-Antigua and Barbuda</option>
            <option value="54">54-Argentina</option>
            <option value="374">374-Armenia</option>
            <option value="297">297-Aruba</option>
            <option value="61">61-Australia</option>
        </select>
     </td>
```

JQuery :-

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $(function() {
            $("#country").val("<?php echo $_POST['country'];?>");
         });
    })
```

Comment: i have this SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' after implement your method. It might be the reason it doesnt work.. but i go through each bracket there wansn't a single bracket missing. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    <?php
(isset($_POST["country"])) ? $country = $_POST["country"] : $country=93; 
?>

<form action='stackover.php' method='POST'>
<select id="country" name="country">
<option <?php if ($country == 93 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="93">93-Afghanistan</option>
<option <?php if ($country == 355 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="355">355-Albania</option>
<option <?php if ($country == 213 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="213">213-Algeria</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```